# splitting a list into smaller lists based on certain characters

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list from a csv file  namely

```
list_from_csv= ["","","1","2","","","3","4"]
```

for my use case i require to get a list that look like this

```
input_list =[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

So basically I want to separate the lists based on the "" delimiter 
I tried something like this initially

```
for i in list_from_csv:
    if i != "":
       input_list.append(i)
```

this however gives me an out put [1,2,3,4]
Is there a trick or command in python to achieve this . Also note I am really new to python , so any help would be appreciated . Also, I tried to look every where for this but couldn't find such an example

Comment: I think that `i == ""` in the question should be `i != ""` ? Otherwise `input_list` would only contain empty chars, right?

Comment: oh sorry you are right I have edited it , but that still gives [1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst= ["","","1","2","","","3","4"]
result = [[int(i) for i in g] for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x!='') if k]
print(result)
# [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

The items are grouped on whether they are empty strings or not. The empty string groups are simply filtered using their group key which is `False`.

Comment: will this cover the case if the list looks like this ["" "1',"2',"3,"  , "4',"5" ,""]

Comment: You should try it out. That list has a mix of `'` and `"`, and I'm not sure if that's a typo

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> [list(map(int, s)) for empty, s in itertools.groupby(list_from_csv, lambda s: s=="") if not empty]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without using any *imported* modules:
the input list was intentionally slightly complicated(for a more complex case)

```
list_from_csv = ["","","1","2","3","","4","5", "", "", "6", "", "7"]

str = [[int(n) for n in i] for i in ''.join([d if d else ' '
       for d in list_from_csv]).strip().split(' ') if i]

print(str)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7]]
```